# Filter browser information from stored useragent data in MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, user-agent

I have stored visitors' `user_agent` info in my MS-SQL database. Each row has this regular format:

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; F-6.0SP2-20041109; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTbORJ/5.14.1.20007)`

Is it possible to filter and display browser information? Something like if string contains `%MSIE 8.0%` then output as IE8, if it contains `%Firefox%` then output as Firefox and etc.

I have searched everywhere and I can't find any help.

Comment: Thank you for an edit. English is my second language.

Comment: Just wanted to add very useful alternative to my original question, instead of storing and polluting database with such long string, you can extract user information using this plug-in http://cssuseragent.org/ and then use value to store it in database.

Comment: More sources: [thedevnotes](http://thedevnotes.allcoolandnew.com/browser-and-os-statistics-from-user-agent-strings-in-mysql/) and [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/t-sql-statement-to-breakdown-useragent-information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to handle that:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 8.0%' THEN 'IE8'
    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Firefox%' THEN 'Firefox'
    ELSE 'There are other browsers?'
    END AS Browser
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can improve this function by adding processing code for more kinds of browsers, or even for bots like GoogleBot, etc. [T-SQL Function: How to parse UserAgent to extract Browser Name](http://www.consultsarath.com/contents/articles/KB000009-tsql-function-how-to-parse-useragent-to-extract-browser-name.aspx)

> In some cases, like Internet Explorer, this is quite simple - just to
>   look for existence of a regular phrase MSIE 6.0 or MSIE 8.0. But with
>   other browsers, this is not simple ... So for each browser, you have to
>   use a different extraction technique to extract the proper Browser
>   Name and Version.
>
> The TSQL function would look like this:
>
> ```
>    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBrowserName](@UserAgent VARCHAR(200))
>    RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
>    AS
>    BEGIN
>    DECLARE @BrowserName VARCHAR(30)
>    SET @BrowserName = CASE
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%MSIE 8.0%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN 'Internet Explorer 8.0'
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%MSIE 7.0%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN 'Internet Explorer 7.0'
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%MSIE 6.0%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN 'Internet Explorer 6.0'
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%MSIE 5.0%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN 'Internet Explorer 5.0'
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%Firefox%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN 'Mozilla ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@UserAgent,
>                        PATINDEX('%Firefox%',@UserAgent), 100),'/', ' ') 
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%Chrome%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN 'Google ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@UserAgent,
>                        PATINDEX('%Chrome%',@UserAgent), 
>                               PATINDEX('%Safari%',@UserAgent) -
>                                      PATINDEX('%Chrome%',@UserAgent)),'/', ' ') 
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%Safari%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN 'Safari ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@UserAgent,
>                        PATINDEX('%Version%',@UserAgent),
>                               PATINDEX('%Safari%',@UserAgent)-
>                                      PATINDEX('%Version%',@UserAgent)),'Version/', '')
>           WHEN PATINDEX('%Opera%',@UserAgent) > 0
>                  THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@UserAgent,
>                        PATINDEX('%Opera%',@UserAgent),
>                               PATINDEX('%(%',@UserAgent)-2),'/', ' ')
>           ELSE
>                  'Unknown Browser'
>           END
>    RETURN(@BrowserName)
>    END
> ```

Comment: @aloisdg - When adding content from another source, always quote the new content. Though unintentional, your previous edit totally changed the tone of this answer and made it sound like the author of *this* post plagiarized someone else's article - which he did not :-)

Comment: @Leigh True. Sorry about that.